# How to find the shortest sequence of swaps between two different permutations?

Tags: algorithm, sequence, permutation, swap

I am looking some kind of an algorithm that would help me to solve a task that stands before me. I need to find out a method to find (NOT only count) all swaps (exchange of two elements) in a given permutation which is required to transform it into another given permutation. It would be great if the method could find the minimum number of swaps leading from one permutation to another.
Could anybody provide me with a tip or a full solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

First determine where each value should go. You'll then find cycles of moves. Take for instance this data:

```
source: [5, 3, 0, 7, 1, 6, 4, 8]
target: [3, 1, 0, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6]
(index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  )
```

Then we can derive that the value at index 0 (which is 5) should go to index 4, and the one at index 4 should go to index 1 and the one at index 1 should go to index 0, making that cycle complete. So we find these cycles:

```
0 -> 4 -> 1 (and back to start)
2
3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 6 (and back to start)
```

So we have three cycles. Note that the value at index 2 is already at its correct index, and so it is in a cycle of its own.

The first cycle can be executed with the following swaps, starting with the last pair, going backwards:

```
index 4 <-> index 1
index 0 <-> index 4
```

No swap is needed for the value at index 2.

The third cycle can be executed with the following swaps:

```
index 7 <-> index 6
index 5 <-> index 7
index 3 <-> index 5
```

The number of swaps to *execute* a cycle is its length minus 1.

So in the above example, the number of swaps is (3-1) + (1-1) + (4-1) = 2 + 0 + 3 = 5.

Comment: A more understandable explanation of your method: [5, 3, 0, 7, 1, 6, 4, 8] -> swap (0,4) -> [1, 3, 0, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8] -> swap(0,1) -> [3, 1, 0, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8]  (first cycle done) -> swap(x,x) -> ...   Giving swap examples before reasoning makes it easier to understand.  Perhaps you want to edit the answer in this way...

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to convert a Starting permutation `S` to a Goal permutation `G`. As pointed out by [tricot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577616/12075306), the goal is to "resolve" a series of cycles that generate in `S` when looking for the positions its elements "should be in" in order to obtain `G`. This "resolve" step can be done in a linear amount of steps in the size of each cycle. Since the total sum of lengths of all cycles does not exceed `n`, the size of the permutation, there must be an algorithm with time complexity `O(n)`. Indeed, there is one. But finding the cycles is not necessarily easy in the original formulation of the problem.

## A simplified version of the problem

In order to find the cycles easily, let's first consider a simplified formulation of our problem where the goal permutation `G` is simply `1 2 3 ... n`. Then, the positions where each number in `S` should be in are easy to find, since these are given by the number themselves.

The cycles in the example `S = 4 3 2 1` can be easily found since there are only two: the first number (`4`) should go to position `4` and the fourth number (`1`) should go to position `1` and that makes the cycle `index 1 -> index 4 -> index 1`. The second is `index 2 -> index 3 -> index 2` (the number in the second position (`3`) should go to position `3` and the number in the third position (`2`) should go to position `2`).

To detect a cycle we only need to find a position `i` such that `S[i] != i` (if `S[i] == i` then we say we a have a fixed point in `S`). Notice that swapping `S[i]` with `S[S[i]]` makes `S[i]` a fixed point in the permutation since it is "sent" to its "rightful" position. Resolving a cycle is simply the procedure to make all numbers in a cycle fixed points in the permutation. In `S = 4 3 2 1`, swapping the first and fourth indices we get `S' = 1 3 2 4`. In `S = 3 1 2 5 4`, we can resolve the cycle `1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1` doing only two swaps

```
index 1 <-> index 3  ==>  S'  = 2 1 3 5 4
index 1 <-> index 2  ==>  S'' = 1 2 3 5 4
```

Notice that every swap shortens the cycle by one unit.

Now, given an `i` such that `S[i] != i`, the following algorithm resolves a cycle

```
while (S[i] != i) {
    swap( S[i], S[S[i]] )
    num_swaps = num_swaps + 1
}
```

Resolving all cycles is easy enough now:

```
function number_of_swaps_simplified(permutation S, permutation G) {
    n = size of G
    num_swaps = 0
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (S[i] != i) {
            swap( S[i], S[S[i]] )
            num_swaps = num_swaps + 1
        }
    }
    return num_swaps
}
```

## The original version of the problem

We can use the function above to solve the more general formulation of the problem where we consider two arbitrary permutations `S` and `G` (needless to say of the same size `n`). We can "normalize" the permutations by relabeling the numbers in `G` to convert it to `1 2 ... n` and relabel the numbers in `S` accordingly.

```
function normalize(permutation S, permutation G) {
    n = size of G
    map = [0 0 ... 0] // an array of n 0's
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        map[G[i]] = i
        G[i] = i
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        S[i] = map[S[i]]
    }
    return S, G
}
```

For example, consider the following permutations and how they are normalized

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6
S = 6 3 4 2 5 1
G = 4 6 1 3 2 5

// map elements of G to get 1 2 3 4 5 6
4 -> 1
6 -> 2
1 -> 3
3 -> 4
2 -> 5
5 -> 6

     1 2 3 4 5 6
S' = 2 4 1 5 6 3
G' = 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Let `S'` and `G'` be the normalized permutations. Obviously, `G'` is `1 2 ... n`. It is easy to see now that the number of swaps to make to go from `S` to `G` is the same as the number of swaps to go from `S'` to `G'`.

```
function number_of_swaps_general(permutation S, permutation G) {
    // normalize S and G prior to calculating the number of swaps
    S', G' = normalize(S, G)
    return number_of_swaps_simplified(S', G')
}
```